# Syntax to express column names of VALUES-clause?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

This is running,

```
val r = sql("SELECT T.* FROM ( VALUES ('xx','xxx','2019-01-01'), ('xxxx','yyyy','2019-01-02') ) T")
```

but *r* have "no name" columns, showed as `col1| col2| col3`. In standard SQL I can express names as table parameters, something as `T(a,b,c)` instead `T`... But this,

```
val r = sql("SELECT T.* FROM ( VALUES ('xx','xxx','2019-01-01'), ('xxxx','yyyy','2019-01-02') ) T(a,b,c)")
```

is not working, it is an **ugly error message**, say nothing about correct Spark syntax for it...

The question is **"How to express column names?"**, and need an example that I can run in spark-shell v2.2.

---

### Notes

The ugly message:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
mismatched input '(' expecting {<EOF>, ',', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'JOIN', 'CROSS', 'INNER', 'LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'FULL', 'NATURAL', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'MINUS', 'INTERSECT', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE', 'ANTI'}(line 1, pos 73)

== SQL ==
SELECT T.*, 'aaa' as chk FROM ( VALUES ('xx','xxx','2019-01-01') ) T (a,b,c)
----------------------------------------------------------------------^^^

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:217)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:637)
  ... 50 elided
```

Comment: what happens if you select like: `select T.col1 as <...>, T.col2 as <...>, T.col3 as <...> from () T` ?

Comment: Hi @mangusta I am looking for correct syntax (there are a Guide?). You suggest to me to not use `VALUES`  clause, so, it is not a solution. Is only a workaround (in your illustration you not say but for multiple values we need `UNION ALL`)

Comment: @mangusta I not understand, but it is one line of code, you can post it as solution, them I can test.

Comment: @mangusta Yes, it is not ideal, but I using it as "best workaround": please post, I will vote up..  but I will  not click as accepted, to wait a better answer

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the dataset `(VALUES (),(),...)` has a predefined column naming (`col1`,`col2`, ...) so the only way to override it, is to use aliases

Since you need columns `a`,`b`,`c` in the val r, it should look like this:
`SELECT T.col1 as a, T.col2 as b, T.col3 as c FROM ( VALUES ('xx','xxx','2019-01-01'), ('xxxx','yyyy','2019-01-02') ) T`

Comment: Thanks @mangusta, to post and the discussion at comments. As I positioned before, it is the "best workaround" but it is not the answer (even for negative answer we need an authoritative "impossible more compact and elegant way" from a Guide that I not see). The use of  `col1`, `col2` etc. names is something arbitrary and also not documented as standard (can change one day with new spark versions)

Answer (score 0):

You can cast this to a dataframe and specify your column names:

```
val r = sql("SELECT T.* FROM ( VALUES ('xx','xxx','2019-01-01'), ('xxxx','yyyy','2019-01-02') ) T").toDF("foo","bar","baz")
```

Or you can use a a different approach to creating your dataframe:

```
val r = Seq(("xx","xxx","2019-01-01"),("xxxx","yyyy","2019-01-02")).toDF("foo","bar","baz")
```

Either way, you will get:

```
r.show
+----+----+----------+
| foo| bar|       baz|
+----+----+----------+
|  xx| xxx|2019-01-01|
|xxxx|yyyy|2019-01-02|
+----+----+----------+
```

Not necessarily any prettier/better than @mangusta's answer, just an alternative approach.